# How can an object detect when it is being disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I can't find an answer to this.

Lets say I have created an object A that contains other objects B, C, etc.

Object A will first be created and added to an observable collection. Later object A is removed from the Observable collection. The ObservableCollection held the only reference to object A.

Is there any way Object A can detect it will be destroyed such that object A can manually call B.dispose and C.dispose and prevent memory leaks?

This is in .Net 4.0, but object B and C are .Net 3.5 or com objects and I'm not sure they will be disposed automatically when A is disposed. (I may be wrong).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dodgy_coder Ojbects B and C are the InkAnalyzer...all my reading indicates that InkAnalyzer.Dispose should be called explicitly when its containing object A is disposed. But this maybe old information.

Comment: I believe its recommended to explicitly call Dispose if you want it garbage collected as soon as possible, however you can quite easily get away with not calling Dispose and just relying on the garbage collector itself to call each object's Finalize method.

Comment: @dodgy_coder your statement is misleading.  If your class holds members which implement Dispose, you should implement dispose and call dispose on those members.  Also it can be beneficial to implement dispose and decouple a class i.e. set it's members to null, this helps the garbage collector detect and collect unused classes.  This is especially true on mobile platforms or mono.

Comment: @dodgy_coder again living up to your name.  If a class implements dispose you should call it immediately after you've finished using it.  How do you know what the implementation of dispose on a class entails and how important it is for it to be called sooner than later?  e.g. not calling dispose on a Stream can cause big problems.  This is what a Using statement is for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Am I falling for a joke here or what?

Comment: @Mick - yes agreed its probably always good to call dispose if you can, but it really depends what you're disposing, right? If as in this case its graphics resources it may not cause an issue if it happens later rather than sooner.

Comment: @dodgy_coder I don't think it depends.  If it implements dispose, call it, ALWAYS.

Comment: @dodgy_coder well I think it actually depends on whether you want a program that leaks memory or runs out of gdi handles or corrupts files etc etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When an object is no longer reachable, it becomes eligible for garbage collection. If it is the sole root for objects it references, they also become eligible for collection. If it has a finalizer, this finalizer will be called by the GC. There are many aspects to understand with respect to deterministic and non-deterministic disposal of objects. Its references may be finalized before it is, or vice-versa. Start here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Problem is I need object A itself to know when it is about to be destroyed so it can first call B.dispose and c.dispose. I don't see an event to attach to.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the dispose pattern. Dispose is for when disposal is explicit, by the program; in this case, A can dispose B and C. However, in your case - finalization - this is when the GC is the trigger. When A becomes eligible for collection, B and C will be too (assuming nothing else references them.) Each object will have its finalizer (destructor) called. At this point A is no longer responsible to handle B and C.

Comment: @xon there should be no harm in calling dispose on an object in the finalizer, you should be able to call on an object multiple times

Comment: @mick this is only true if dealing with managed objects that have idempotent disposal implementations. unmanaged references are much more fragile.

Comment: I think you need to be careful with this sort of advice.  It's very easy for large graphs of objects to become unreachable by the app domain that the garbage collector may not collect. THe garbage collector is not fool-proof.   It often needs your help... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx

Comment: I think you need to be careful with this sort of advice. Most people are not smarter than the garbage collector. The GC has gone through many changes since 2007 (the date of your referenced article.) And you are only reinforcing my point about unmanaged references.

Comment: I read it seven years ago when it was first written. Without the proper context, it is hard to take any of the specific points on board. The OP's langauge indicates he is unfamiliar with basic disposal patterns. I am keeping it simple. You are diving into the arcane.

Comment: @mick - your answer is still sound, but that's not the point. I think the biggest point of confusion for most people is thinking calling dispose is performing garbage collection.

Comment: It's not that arcane, it's actually pretty common especially in rich client apps, even more especially on rich client apps running on mono or windows phone.  WPF / Windows forms often have large numbers of objects all of which are referencing each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dispose Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) for this case. I am not sure if this can help you case. But if you are the owner of Object B & C then you can have dispose pattern implemented in B & C so that A can call b.dispose / c.dispose whenever its done.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement Dispose on Object A and ensure it is called when removed from the collection.  It's an observable collection so you should be able to get an object to subscribe to the collection and call dispose on objects removed from the collection which implement IDispose.

The [Dispose Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) calls dispose in the Finalizer simply as a fail safe, it's not intended to be the primary means of ensuring objects are disposed correctly, ideally you should be calling Dispose as soon as the object is no longer needed.